# JavaFX11 and Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, openjfx

I followed the instruction in this link 
https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx 
and when i run javafx sample i get this error

```
Error:(3, 26) java: cannot access javafx.application.Application
  bad class file: C:\Program Files\Java\OpenJDK\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib\javafx.graphics.jar(javafx/application/Application.class)
    class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

and when i go to Project Structure > Project/Modules the JDK is set to JDK11
VM option:

```
--module-path C:\Program Files\Java\OpenJDK\javafx-sdk-11.0.1\lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

I tried to go to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler
Project bytecode version was set to 8 and i changed it to 11 and the first error was gone but i got new error

```
Error:java: invalid target release: 11
```

I was searching on the internet and somebody said go to `.idea\compiler.xml` and set target to 11 but it's already set to 11 for me but i get the error

Comment: Are you sure that your JDK is set to the right version?

Comment: yes i'm sure it's set to JDK 11 but it still says javac 8 was used to compile

Comment: That would imply that the JDK is not set to 11 if it's still using 8 to compile...

Comment: if it's using jdk 8 then how do i stop it from using that because in project setting i did set it to jdk 11

Comment: Are you using something like Maven or Gradle to handle the build?

Comment: I haven't used gradle or maven ....

Comment: what should i set my project language level ?

Comment: Make sure you have JDK 11 [set for the module and the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#define-sdk) and language level is set to 11 for project and module settings.

Answer (score 1):

Go To File > Project Structure > Modules > Source

Set Language Level to 11 (if 11 not Available set to "X-Experimental Features")

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz5z5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the error, could not find proper solution either, so I figured out myself.

**Problem location:** *pom.xml* - maven file

Sometimes issue can happen with different JavaFX entity, for instance with FXMLLoader or EventHandler:

1. `java: cannot access javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader   bad class file: ... class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 53.0`
2. `java: cannot access javafx.event.EventHandler   bad class file: /Users/john/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/12/javafx-base-12-mac.jar!/javafx/event/EventHandler.class     class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 53.0`

---

Fixed version of pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hkr</groupId>
    <artifactId>CommunicationTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>9</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

Incorrect (previous verison):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hkr</groupId>
    <artifactId>CommunicationTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

The issue is in **properties** tag, the target version was below JDK version (9.0.1), which was causing in my case a problem of `"class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 53.0"`.

I simply changed to **target** **9** instead of **1.8** and it got fixed.